# How to check if a file is in a local drive in Air / Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

In Adobe Air, is there any way to check if the path of a file belongs to a local (non-network) drive?

I mainly would need to use this in Windows, but if there was a cross-platform approach it would be even better.

I know that c: and d: are the usual local drives in Windows. However, there is no rule for other letters, and it is these cases that I am after.

Answer (score 0):

I've read up about this a long back ago, you can look it up here

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/StorageVolume.html#isRemovable

Comment: I guess, you may not be able to find out from this info

Comment: Both local and network drives are listed by StorageVolume as non-removable, so this doesn't with the OP's problem.

Comment: Some of the other programming languages can find out if the drive is a network drive or a system drive, you can write a native program and have the native program connect to flex using sockets to solve your problem.